# Is there a rule for “‑ance” vs. “‑ence”?

Tags: orthography, suffixes, latin, ance-ence

OK, so I’m ashamed to admit that as a native speaker I think I’ve missed something somewhere. I was typing up some documentation and spellchecker kept bugging me.  So I looked up some words and found this:

> The suffixes *‑ance* and *‑ence* mean
>   “quality of” or “state of.” Words
>   ending in these suffixes are usually
>   nouns. There is no rule that governs
>   whether a word ends with 
>   *‑ance* or *‑ence*.

Even the dictionary on my Mac goes so far as to say:

> ORIGIN from French *‑ence*, from Latin
>   *‑entia, ‑antia* (from present participial stems *‑ent‑, ‑ant‑*). Since
>   the 16th cent. many inconsistencies
>   have occurred in the use of *‑ence* and
>   *‑ance*.

Is this for real?  There really is no rule?

Comment: You shouldn't really be too surprised. (Natural) Language comes first, rules are imposed upon it long after. Only in artificial languages such as the programming ones are the rules and the language itself co-created.

Comment: @mickeyf, no, there are natural rules that people follow.  Even ebonics has a pretty strict grammar structure, phrases such as "who dat?" are perfectly understandable to the people who speak and listen to it, even if they don't codify it as rules.  Without any kind of rules (codified or not) communication wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @mickeyf: I guess you both need to agree on the definition of "rules".  It sounds to me that mickeyf is talking about prescriptive rules, which are applied at some point in the middle of the life of a language, and you are talking about rules in the sense of structured grammar that all language speakers must necessarily have.  I think what this really boils down to is that written language is a synthetic thing and rules for spelling can be inconsistent and even contradictory at times.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is for real. No, there really is no rule. There used to be a rule in Latin, though. Etymonline [explains](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ance) in more detail:

> **-ance**
> suffix attached to verbs to form abstract nouns of process or fact (*convergence* from *converge*), or of state or quality (*absence* from *absent*); ultimately from L. *-antia* and *-entia*, which depended on the vowel in the stem word. As Old French evolved from Latin, these were leveled to *-ance*, but later French borrowings from Latin (some of them subsequently passed to English) used the appropriate Latin form of the ending, as did words borrowed by English directly from Latin (*diligence*, *absence*). English thus inherited a confused mass of words from French and further confused it since c.1500 by restoring *-ence* selectively in some forms of these words to conform with Latin. Thus *dependant*, but *independence*, etc.

Comment: +1 This process of borrowings was indeed even more chaotic than I already suspected.

Comment: @RegDwight, serious comment: thanks for the answer.  `dependant` shows up as misspelled though on Google and my Mac.  Have these been changing back in recent years or something because I feel like my brain is rotting trying to figure all this stuff out. (writing code has borrowed too much of my language regions..)

Comment: @Stephen: as an adjective, *dependant* is the obsolete spelling of *dependent*. As a noun, it is *dependant* in the UK, but *dependent* in the US, where *dependant* would be considered a misspelling.

Comment: @RegDwight, how obsolete is obsolete?  50 years, 100 years?

Comment: @Stephen: that would make an interesting question on itself. I don't know the answer right now.

Comment: @RegDwight, I only ask because I did a lot of classical/British literature reading (Jane Eyre, KJ 1611 Bible, Robin Hood, Original Tarzans, Warhammer 40K etc) and I've got a horrible mix of UK/US english in me.  It took me forever to stop spelling "centre" and I still do it by accident sometimes.

Comment: From what I understand then, there is no rule for ance and ence suffixes. If this is the case, I need not be concerned with the spelling of those suffixes, as the meaning conveyed by both. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There are four conjugations of verbs in Latin, verbs that end in -are, -ēre, -ere, and -ire. The four conjugations are still evident in Spanish, French, Italian, etc. In English nouns that derive from these verbs end with -antia, -entia, and -ientia, from which we eventually get our nouns ending with -ance, -ence, and -ience.

e.g. parlance is from parlare, insurgence is from insurgere, audience is from audire. So remembering the spelling in English helps if you studied Latin ;)

However, standard spelling in English wasn't a huge priority until people like Samuel Johnson started writing dictionaries, so there are all sorts of exceptions to these rules.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there seems to have some rules to that in English according to a blogger I've found on Oxford Dictionaries:

> **-ance or -ence?**
>
> These endings are used to make nouns, meaning either: a quality or
>   state (e.g. ignorance is the state of being ignorant about something)
>   or an action (e.g. emergence is the action of emerging from
>   somewhere).
>
> One key way of knowing which ending to choose is to be aware of the
>   words that these nouns are formed from. Some are made from verbs (e.g.
>   performance from perform) and some are from adjectives (for example
>   intelligence from intelligent).
>
> **-ance**
>
> If the word is formed from a verb that ends in -y, -ure, or -ear, then
>   the ending of the noun will be spelled -ance, for example:
>
> Verb: apply comply / Noun: appliance compliance
>
> (...)
>
> If the noun is related to a verb which ends in -ate, then the ending
>   is likely to be -ance, for instance:
>
> Verb: deviate dominate / Noun: deviance dominance      (...)
>
> A further tip is that, if the stem of the word (the part before the
>   ending) ends in a ‘hard’ c (pronounced like the c in cab) or a ‘hard’
>   g (pronounced like the g in get), then the ending will be spelled
>   -ance. For example: significance; elegance.
>
> As for the other nouns which end in -ance, there are no hard-and-fast
>   rules, so you may find it helpful to memorize them. Here’s a handy
>   list of the most common:
>
> ABUNDANCE acceptance acquaintance
>
> (...)
>
> **-ence**
>
> If the word is formed from a verb ending in -ere, then the ending will
>   be spelled -ence. For example:
>
> Verb: adhere cohere   / Noun: adherence coherence
>
> (...)
>
> So, you may ask, why is perseverance (from persevere) spelled -ance?
>   Sorry, it’s simply an exception to this rule…
>
> Does the related verb end in a stressed -er syllable? If yes, then
>   -ence is the correct ending, as in:
>
> Verb: confer infer / Noun: conference inference
>
> (...)
>
> Note that, although the verb differ is stressed on the first syllable
>   rather than the final –er, difference is still spelled with -ence at
>   the end. If the word contains the syllables -cid-, -fid-, -sid-, or
>   -vid- immediately before the ending, the correct suffix is -ence. For instance:
>
> CONFIDENCE evidence
>
> (...)
>
> If the stem of the word ends in a soft c (pronounced like the c in
>   cell) or a soft g (pronounced like the g in gin), then the ending will
>   be -ence. For example:
>
> ADOLESCENCE indulgence
>
> (...)
>
> Again, some words don’t follow these rules (or the ‘rules’ have
>   several exceptions, so can be rather difficult to learn). Here’s a
>   list of some common nouns ending in -ence:
>
> ABSENCE   DEPENDENCE  OBEDIENCE
>
> (...)

And much more at: http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/05/ance-ence-suffixes/

Answer (score 1):

The following is meant to supplement not supplant existing answers.  In general, you look at what it was in Latin; however, there are several prominent exceptions.

The Etymonline entry regarding this is cribbed and abbreviated from the OED. Here’s what the OED says about these.

## *‑ance* and *‑ence*

> ### ‑ance
>
> a. Fr. *‑ance* :– L. *‑ānt‑ia*, *‑ēnt‑ia*, *‑ent‑ia*
>   (see **‑ence**), all of which in words that survived into Fr., or were
>   formed in Fr. as nouns of action, on the pres. pple., were levelled under
>   *‑ance*. But other L. words of this form, subseq. adopted in Fr., took
>   *‑ence* or *‑ance*, according to L. spelling. Thus of popular preservation
>   or formation, *aidance*, *assistance*, *complaisance*, *nuisance*,
>   *parlance*, *séance*; of later learned adoption from L., *absence*,
>   *clémence*, *différence*, *diligence*, *providence*, *prudence*, as well as
>   *élégance*, *tempérance*. Words of both classes were adopted in Eng. in
>   their actual Fr. forms, which they still generally retain. But, since 1500,
>   various words orig. in *‑ance* from Fr. have been altered back to *‑ence*,
>   after L.; and all words recently adopted from L., directly or through
>   mod.Fr., or formed on L. analogies, have taken *‑ence* or *‑ance* according
>   to the L. vowel. Hence, mod.E. words in *‑ance* partly represent L.
>   *‑āntia*, but largely L.  *‑entia*, *‑ēntia*, through OFr. *‑ance*; partly
>   also mod.Fr. *‑ance* from vbs. of various origin. On the other hand, OFr.
>   *‑ance* :– L. *‑entia*, *‑ēntia*, is, in consequence of refashioning,
>   partly represented by Eng. *‑ence*. For the confusion and inconsistency
>   which this causes in current spelling, as in *dependance*, *‑dence*,
>   *resistance*, *subsistence*, see **‑ence**. As, in many cases, the OFr.
>   vbs. themselves, as well as their derivatives in *‑ance*, were adopted in
>   Eng. (e.g. *appear ‑ance*, *assist ‑ance*, *purvey ‑ance*, *suffer ‑ance*),
>   the suffix became to a certain extent a living formative, and was occas.
>   used to form similar nouns of action on native vbs., as *abid‑ance*,
>   *abear‑ance*, *forbear‑ance*, *further‑ance*, *hinder‑ance*, *ridd‑ance*,
>   etc. For meaning, see **‑ence**; and cf. **‑ancy**.
>
> ## ‑ence
>
> a. Fr. *‑ence*, ad. L. *‑entia*, forming abstr. sbs., usually of 
>   quality, rarely of action, on ppl. stems in *‑ent‑*, e.g. *sapient‑em*
>   knowing, *sapient‑ia* knowingness, sapience; *audient‑em* hearing,
>   *audient‑ia* the process of hearing, audience. As the ppl. stem had
>   *‑ent‑*, *‑ant‑*, the derivative sbs. had *‑entia* (*prūdentia*), *‑antia*
>   (*īnfantia*); but all these were levelled in OFr. to *‑ance*, in words that
>   survived in popular use, or were formed analogically on the pr. pple. in
>   *‑ant*; as *aidance*, *assistance*, *complaisance*, *contenance*,
>   *nuisance*, *parlance*, *séance*. These were sbs. of action or process, the
>   value with which the suffix was retained in Fr. as a living formative. But
>   subsequently other L. words in *‑ntia*, which had not survived in the
>   living language, were readopted on the analogy of these, but with *‑ence*
>   or *‑ance* according to the L. vowel, e.g. *absence*, *clémence*,
>   *diligence*, *élégance*, *présence*, *providence*, *prudence*,
>   *tempérance*, *violence*. These were sbs. of quality or state; all Fr.
>   words in *‑ence* are of this class. Both classes were adodpted in ME. in
>   their actual Fr. forms and senses, which they generally still retain; but
>   since 1500, some of those in *‑ance* have been altered back to *‑ence*
>   after L. All words since adopted from or formed on L., follow L. precedent
>   as to *‑ence* or *‑ance*. The result is that the modern spelling of
>   individual words, and still more of groups of cogn. words, is uncertain and
>   discordant; cf. assist*ance*, consist*ence*, exist*ence*, resist*ance*,
>   subsist*ence*; attend*ance*, superintend*ence*; ascend*ant*, *‑ent*,
>   *‑ancy*, *‑ency*, condescend*ence*; depend*ant*, *‑ent*, *‑ance*, *‑ence*,
>   independ*ence*; appear*ance*, appar*ent*; pertin*ence*, appurten*ance*. In
>   sense, words in *‑nce* are partly nouns of action, as in OFr., partly of
>   state or quality, as in L. The latter idea is more distinctly expressed by
>   the variant *‑ncy* (see **‑y** = *‑ie* :– *‑ia*) which has been formed in
>   Eng. as a direct adaptation of L. *‑ntia*; see **‑ency**, **‑ancy**.

## *‑ant* and *‑ent*

> ### *‑ant*
>
> a. Fr. *‑ant*, sometimes :– L. *‑entem*, *‑āntem*, *‑ēntem*, ending of
>   pres. pple. (see **‑ent**); sometimes a later adaptation of *‑āntem* only.
>   All the participial forms were in OFr.  levelled under *‑ant*, the sole
>   ending of the pr.  pple., as L. *amānt‑*, *vidēnt‑*, *sedēnt‑*,
>   *crēdent‑em* in Fr.  *amant*, *voyant*, *séant*, *croyant*. But other words
>   were subsequently adopted in their L. stem form, as *prudent*, *présent*,
>   *élégant*. Hence Fr. words in *‑ant* are of two kinds, one answering to L.
>   *‑ānt*, the other to L. *‑ent*, *‑ēnt*. All were adopted, in their actual
>   Fr. forms, in Eng., where they subseq. became *‑ˈau.nt*; then again, with
>   the change of stress, *‑ant*, as L.  *affīdent‑em*, *diffī‑dent‑em*,
>   *plicānt‑em*, *servient‑em*, *tenēnt‑em*, OFr. *afiant*, *defiant*,
>   *pliant*, *serjeant*, *tenant*, ME.  *afiˈa(u).nt*, *defiˈa(u).nt*,
>   *pliˈa(u).nt*, *serjeˈau.nt*, *teˈnau.nt*.  Most of them retain *‑ant*,
>   e.g. *claimant*, *pleasant*, *poursuivant*, *servant*, *suppliant*,
>   *valiant*; but since 1500 some have been refashioned with *‑ent* after L.,
>   wholly (as *apparaunt*, *‑ent*), or partly (as in *pendant*, *‑ent*,
>   *dependant*, *‑ent*, *ascendant*, *‑ent*).  Hence, inconsistency and
>   uncertainty in the present spelling of many words, in which L. and Fr.
>   analogies are at variance: see **‑ent**. Many new words of this class have
>   been adopted from L. *‑āntem* directly or through later Fr., or have been
>   formed on L. analogies, or adopted from mod.Fr. and Romance *‑ant*,
>   *‑ante*; as *concomitant*, *protestant*, *commandant*, *anæsthesiant*. For
>   sense, see **‑ent**.
>
> ### *‑ent*
>
> a. Fr. *‑ent*, ad. L. *‑ent‑em*, the ending of pr. pples. of vbs. of the
>   2nd, 3rd, and 4th conjugation, as *rīdent‑em*, *currentem*, *audientem*.
>   (In the pples. of the 3rd and 4th conjugation this ending represents OAryan
>   *‑nt‑*, or perh. *‑ent‑*, of the ablaut‑series *‑ent‑*, *‑ont‑*, *‑nt‑*;
>   cf. Skr. *‑ant‑*, *‑at‑*, Gr. *‑οντ‑*, Goth. *‑and‑*, OE. *‑end‑*; in those
>   of the 2nd conjugation it represents this suffix combined with the thematic
>   *‑e‑* of the vb.; similarly the *‑ant‑* of the 1st conjugation includes a
>   thematic *‑a‑*.) In OFr. this suffix and the corresponding *‑ant‑em* of the
>   1st conjugation were levelled under *‑ant*, the sole ending of the Fr. pr.
>   pple., as *riant*, *courant*, *mourant*, *levant* ( :– L. *levantem*). At a
>   later time many L. forms in *‑ent‑*, which had acquired an adj.  sense,
>   were adopted in Fr. as adjs. with the *‑ent‑* unchanged, as *diligent*,
>   *évident*; some of these were duplicates of living ppl. forms in *‑ant*, as
>   *convénient* = **convenant**, **provident** = **pourvoyant**, **confident**
>   = **confiant**. The Fr. words in *‑ant*, *‑ent*, which were adopted into
>   Eng., have generally retained the form of the suffix which they had in Fr.;
>   but since 1500 there has been a tendency to refashion them after Lat., and
>   hence several words in *‑ant* have changed that ending for *‑ent*, either
>   entirely or in certain senses. In mod.Eng. also many Lat. words in *‑entem*
>   have been directly adopted, always in the form *‑ent*. The conflict between
>   Eng. and Fr. analogies occasions frequent inconsistency and uncertainty in
>   the present spelling of words with this suffix; cf. e.g. *assistant*,
>   *persistent*; *attendant*, *superintendent*; *dependant*, *‑ent*,
>   *independent*.
>
> 2. In sense the words in *‑ent*, *‑ant* are primarily adjs., sometimes
>      distinctly ppl., as *convergent*, *obsolescent*, *errant*, *peccant*; some,
>      however, are, like many words of the same type in Lat. and Fr., used as
>      sbs. (either in addition to the adj. use or exclusively), meaning (*a*) a
>      personal agent, as *agent*, *claimant*, *president*, *regent*; (*b*) a
>      material agent, as *coefficient*, *current*, *ingredient*, *secant*,
>      *tangent*, *torrent*; *esp.* in *Medicine*, as *aperient*, *astringent*,
>      *emollient*, *expectorant*.